# How can i resolve the error of nullpointerexception while writing to excel file in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Getting nullpointerexception error while writing data to excel file. I am getting this error **Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.setCellValue(String)" because "cell3Update" is null.**

**cell3update** is used in the writeSignup method.

Below is the given code

```
public class WriteExcel {
    public void writeLogin(String result) {
        String excelFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resource/TestData.xls";

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Login");
            Cell cell2Update = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);
            cell2Update.setCellValue(result);
            inputStream.close();

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resource/TestData.xls");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void writeSignup(String result) {
        String excelFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resource/TestData.xls";

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Signup");
            Cell cell3Update = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(6);
            cell3Update.setCellValue(result);
            inputStream.close();

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resource/TestData.xls");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

writelogin method is working perfectly fine but getting error in writeSignup method. I have used almost identical code for both but still one is working fine and one is throwing above error.
Kindly help me resolve this.

Comment: You need to check if the row or the cell is null, and create a new row/cell accordingly and add it to the sheet, for example `Row row = sheet.createRow(1);`. See the API doc showing that null may be returned for an undefined [row](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow-int-) or [cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#getCell-int-)

Comment: but why my writelogin method is working perfectly fine and if i am using createrow then it is deleting all my previous data entered in that row.

Comment: writelogin isn't trying to write to cell(6)... best to check for nulls in either though.

Comment: The issue is the cell at index 6, not the row, that was just an example.

Comment: With writelogin method i am also trying to write in a blank cell and its perfectly doing its job and same is the case here only different sheet and different cell and I want to write data in a specific cell.  @sorifiend

Comment: A blank cell that "exists" can be written into without issue, your problem is that the cell doesn't exist, and that is why you need to create it (A sheet does not create 9999x9999+ rows/cells, it keeps a record of the smallest amount, and the rest are null until you create them). Any sheet row or cell can return null, and you should always check to make sure it is not null, or create a new row/cell if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay. will try. Thanks. @sorifiend

Comment: Thanks @sorifiend Tested it and it worked like charm. Posting the code in the answer so that if anyone who need it can take help.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer in the comment section of this post. Pasting the code here

```
package Utility;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class WriteExcel extends ReadExcel{
    public void writeLogin(String result) {
        String excelFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resource/TestData.xls";

        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Login");
            Cell cell2Update = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);
            cell2Update.setCellValue(result);
            inputStream.close();

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resource/TestData.xls");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void writeSignup(String result) {
        String excelFilePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resource/TestData.xls";
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Signup");
            Cell cell3Update = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(6);
            if(cell3Update == null)  //Made some changes here
            {
                cell3Update = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(6);
            }
            cell3Update.setCellValue(result);
            
            inputStream.close();

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resource/TestData.xls");
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            workbook.close();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

Hope it will help you too.
Thanks.